# Kali Linux keeps getting stuck during Configuring the network during install from USB

Tags: kali-linux

I'm trying to install Kali from a USB, and everything seems fine until you try to get to the point of inputting your hostname.

Everythings fine; The language selection and other stuff like CD-ROM works fine, the interfaces get probed and I always choose wlan0 as I don't have Ethernet. It's just when I connect to my wifi that it happens: I connect to the wifi with the password and it seems fine until it completes the DCHP Autoconfiguration. It stays blank, I can still move the mouse and everything, but, there's a blank screen: The Kali logo is still there, the Configure the network tag is also there.

Apart from that the rest is blank, no buttons no prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I've done some more tests, stumbled across some new info and I think I have a definitive plan... this works for DVD's and USB's, so don't fret.

Whether or not you are missing firmware drivers is half the problem for me, so I'm including that as it should speed up the whole detecting network devices section anyway. When grub pops up (menu to select live, persistent, install, etc...)

1. go to advanced
2. go to text install
3. hit alt+f2 when it loads
4. hit enter to activate console
5. type `nano /bin/check-missing-firmware`
6. directly below `#! /bin/sh` type `exit 0` (hit enter on the beginning of the second line and go back to it)
7. type 'exit' and hit enter
8. hit ctrl+alt+f1
9. start the install at the first entry or enter your language (I don't remember which one happens)
10. when you get to the network portion just hit cancel on everything and skip it when the prompt gives you options (enter should do the trick). *If you miss it, just hit esc and you'll see a menu listing different select-able actions. pick the one after configure network*
11. don't use a mirror
12. it should install just fine now. run `get-apt update` and `get-apt dist-upgrade` after logging in

**IMPORTANT:** I just installed this on a decade's old tower and noticed that the sources.list for /etc/apt was empty. If apt-get update doesn't seem to do anything, type `nano /bin/apt/sources.list`

Once you are there you'll want to check for

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib 
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

If you don't see them, paste it. Doesn't really matter where, but you should probably do it further up.

The apt-get update was rather quick, but active, nonetheless. The apt-get distro-install on the other hand... over an hour on all of my PC's, but it has finished quicker on the tower, which makes no sense.

**UPDATE:** Apparently running apt-get update still did something after the dist-upgrade, so I'm playing it safe and just repeatedly executing those commands. Another issue is it will likely tell you to restart wmd and xmd and install postgresql-11. Don't worry about those.

You will need to hard restart (the restart function will just take you to login), you login, the prompt disappears and it just stays on the background

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by disabling the network card. I didn't have it, so instead I was using a dongle for WiFi. After removing the dongle and retrying the installation it gave me an option to configure the network later.